# Angular 2 ts file modifications not detected

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

Hi everyone I am trying to learn angular2 and I'm using Visual Sutio 2015.
I made an angular2 project in a web application in visual studio. Everything was working well, I could make changes, create a new component typescript was compiling and in the browser was displayed the content of my template. I made that project on a computer that was not mine so I copy it on a usb key to be able to work on it on my computer. When I run the project it's still working, it stills displays the content, but when I create a new component or make changes on the existing one from typescript file, there is no changes in the javascript file neither in the browser... I don't know how but for a moment changes in typescript appeard also in javascript file, but still not in the browser, I closed the project and reopen it and now it's like I'm no making any changes at all, I don't know what to do.. I'm using gulp to compile the files :

gulp file :

```
/// <binding />
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');

var destPath = './libs/';

// Delete the dist directory
gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src(destPath)
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task("scriptsNStyles", () => {
    gulp.src([
            'core-js/client/**',
            'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'reflect-metadata/**',
            'rxjs/**',
            'zone.js/dist/**',
            '@angular/**',
            'jquery/dist/jquery.*js',
            'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.*js'
    ], {
        cwd: "node_modules/**"
    })
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./libs"));
});

gulp.task("html",
    function() {
        gulp.src(["tsScripts/**/*.html"])
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./Scripts'));
    });

var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsScripts/tsconfig.json', {
    typescript: require('typescript')
});
gulp.task('ts', function (done) {
    //var tsResult = tsProject.src()
    var tsResult = gulp.src([
            "tsScripts/**/*.ts"
    ])
        .pipe(ts(tsProject), undefined, ts.reporter.fullReporter());
    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('./Scripts'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['watch.ts']);

gulp.task('watch.ts', ['ts'], function () {
    return gulp.watch('tsScripts/**/*.ts', ['ts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['scriptsNStyles','html', 'watch']);
```

tsconfig :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../Scripts/AppClient",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/index",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

What am I missing?

What I have tried:

I tried to reinstall npm and typescript, rebuild the project, close and reopen the project I have tried some solution give on stackoverflow like in put "compileOnSave : true" in the tsconfig, nothing is making any difference

Comment: Is your typescript compiler throwing any errors ?

Comment: No, but I found the solution I just run the gulp task watch in the Task Runner Explorer and everything works